# Changing TextView text from dialog in android

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I have a `ListView` which has items (each has `Button` to edit and `TextView` showing title). I've implemeted custom adapter to show this structure.

On edit button's click, I show a dialog with `EditText` and OK button. User can enter desired name in `EditText` and that text should change the title in `ListView`.

Sample of my code is,

```
mListViewItemsAccCat.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
{
    final TextView textviewTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);

    Button objButtonEdit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        objButtonEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            // here displaying dialog and imageButton is OK button
            final EditText editTextTitle = (EditText) dialogEdit.findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
            ImageButton imageButtonOK = (ImageButton) dialogEdit.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
            imageButtonOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                String strNewTitle = editTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
                textviewTitle.setText(strNewTitle);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here the text of `ListView` item should change as `strNewTitle`. But it is not changing. Where I'm getting wrong?

**UPDATE:** I checked debugging. The text of `TextView` is getting changed internally but it is not showing. (The `mText` of `TextView` holds new value but in UI, it still shows old value).

Comment: Could be the final declaration.. try defining it outside as a global variable without the final.. private TextView textviewTitle; and then in your OnClicklistener: textviewTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);

Comment: @Wicked161089: Not working.

Comment: Did you try like mentioned below calling Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after setText() in your OnClick Method?

Comment: Do this : You will be having array of Strings, after you edit item, change the item text in array and then use notifyDataSetChanged().

Answer (score 0):

Did you use convertView in your adapter.getView function? What's the code in your getView function? In your imageButtonOK's onClickListener, instead of changing the TextView's content directly, you should change the data in your model and then call adapter.notifyDataChanged() function.